# Can I use a 3D input on a Keras Dense Layer?

Tags: keras, text-classification, keras-layer, word-embedding, nlp

As an exercise I need to use only dense layers to perform text classifications. I want to leverage words embeddings, the issue is that the dataset then is 3D (samples,words of sentence,embedding dimension). Can I input a 3D dataset into a dense layer?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can try TimeDistributed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in [the keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) you can use 3D (or higher rank) data as input for a Dense layer but the input gets flattened first:

> Note: if the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then it is flattened prior to the initial dot product with kernel.

This means that if your input has shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, dim)`, then the dense layer will first flatten your data to shape `(batch_size * sequence_length, dim)` and then apply a dense layer as usual. The output will have shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_units)`. This is actually the same as applying a Conv1D layer with kernel size 1, and it might be more explicit to use a Conv1D layer instead of a Dense layer.

Comment: I know, but we are asked to only use dense layers. Otherwise I wouldn't even try that. Thanks anyway!